# PHP/MySQL - CSV parse with functions results in "METHOD NOT ALLOWED" when over 28 rows are uploaded

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have created a `PHP` `CSV parser`. My customer uploads a csv file there with data of his customers, the csv is exploded into rows and further into cells.

Finally the cells are uploaded to corresponding MySQL database, sent via `XML SoapCall` to an external database and in the end echoed onto documents body with statuses of every row sent.

It works perfectly fine for **up to 28 rows in CSV**, but whenever there are more rows to be added a

> 500 Internal Error
>   The server encountered an internal error and could not complete your request.

pops in and would **stop the update/soapcall/echo loop**.

Any ideas what may this be caused by?

Memory cache limit is set to 256mb while max uploaded file size is 64mb, dont think any of those have been exceeded.

**EDIT1**:

It actually seems like the problem were spaces in some of the cells. Now however it would stop at row 28 and bring error **500 Internal Error
The server encountered an internal error and could not complete your request.**.

Any ideas?

**EDIT2** code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_FILES["filetoparse"]['tmp_name'])) {
    } else {
        die("Błąd wgrywania pliku");
    }
    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES["filetoparse"]['tmp_name']);
    if (isset($file)) {

    } else {
        die("Błąd odczytu pliku.");
    }
    function array_to_xml($array, &$xml) {
                foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                    if(is_array($value)) {
                        if(!is_numeric($key)){
                            $subnode = $xml->addChild("$key",'','');
                            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
                        } else {
                            array_to_xml($value, $xml);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $xml->addChild("$key","$value",'');
                    }
                }
            };
    $echo = "";
    $rows = explode("\n", $file);
    array_shift($rows);
    foreach($rows as $row => $data) {
        $row_data = explode(';', $data);
        $info[$row]['name']             = $row_data[0];
        $info[$row]['city']          = $row_data[1];
        $info[$row]['postalcode']            = $row_data[2];
        $info[$row]['pesel']             = $row_data[3];
        $info[$row]['phone']         = $row_data[4];
        $info[$row]['amount']         = $row_data[5];
        $info[$row]['sex']         = $row_data[6];

        $name = $info[$row]['name'];
        $city = $info[$row]['city'];
        $postcode = $info[$row]['postalcode'];
        $pesel = $info[$row]['pesel'];
        $phone = $info[$row]['phone'];
        $price = $info[$row]['amount'];
        $xmlsex = $info[$row]['sex'];
        $xmlsexx = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $xmlsex);
        $names = explode(' ', $name);
        $firstname = $names[0];
        $lastname = $names[1];

        if (empty($pesel)) {
            continue;
        }
        // Api Fines.pl module   

            $client = new SoapClient("SOME_API");

            $contract = array(
                'product' => array(
                    'prefix' => 'MOP',
                ),
                'participants' => array(
                    'customers' => array(
                        'main_borrower' => array(
                            'personal_data' => array(
                                'pesel' => $pesel,
                                'firstname' => $firstname,
                                'lastname' => $lastname,
                                'sex' => $xmlsexx,
                            ),
                            'contact_data' => array(
                                'addresses' => array(
                                    'address' => array(
                                        'type' => 'registered',
                                        'street_name' => $city,
                                        'block_number' => '1',
                                        'flat_number' => '1',
                                        'postal_code' => $postcode,
                                        'city' => $city,
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'phones_mobile' => array(
                                    'phone_mobile' => array(
                                        'type' => 'personal',
                                        'number' => $phone,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            'incomes' => array(
                                'income' => array(
                                    'type' => 'employment',
                                    'main_income' => 'true',
                                    'fixed_term_contract' => 'false',
                                    'paychecks' => array(
                                        'paycheck' => array(
                                            'amount_net' => array(
                                                'amount' => $price,
                                                'currency' => 'PLN',
                                            ),
                                            'type' => 'base',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            );

            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><sof:Contract xmlns:s=\"http://www.fines.pl/simple\" xmlns:sof=\"http://www.fines.pl/sof\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.fines.pl/sof model.xsd \"></sof:Contract>");

            array_to_xml($contract, $xml);

                $parameters = array(
                'user_login' => 'XXX',
                'user_password' => 'XXX',
                'contract' => $xml->asXML(),
                );
                $response = $client->newApplication($parameters);
                $responsearray = get_object_vars($response);
                if ($response->success) {
                    $finesaccepted = "Tak - " . $response->number_sof;
                } else {
                    $finesaccepted = "Nie - " . $response->messages->message->text;
                }
                $finesaccepted = str_replace("'", "", $finesaccepted);

                //into database
                $mysqli = new mysqli('XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX');
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $date = date("U");
                if ($xmlsexx == 'male') {
                    $querysex = "Mężczyzna";
                } else {
                    $querysex = "Kobieta";
                }
                $insertquery = "INSERT INTO x_form (ref_id, date, firstname, lastname, check_rules, ip_adres, email, phone, type, company, nip, postcode, city, amount, income, pesel, sex, isfb, finesaccepted) VALUES ('$date', '$date', '$firstname', '$lastname', '1', '$ip', 'brak', '$phone', '4', NULL, NULL, '$postcode', '$city', NULL, '$price', '$pesel', '$querysex', '2', '$finesaccepted')";
                $echo .= $firstname . " " . $lastname . " - Dodano do bazy. Przyjęto w Fines: " . $finesaccepted . "<br>";
                $mysqli->query($insertquery);
                sleep(1);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: _dont think any of those have been exceeded._ Did you check the logs?

Comment: Having some code to look at may help.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Updated question with more detail on current issue. How may i check them?

Comment: @NigelRen Updated question with more detail on current issue. Seems like it's not code-related issue i think, more like too much elements are to be `echo`ed maybe?

Comment: More data validation required posibly?

Comment: Depends how you are processing the file, it may be that line 28 has a quote in one of the fields.  Without the code or the data it's just guesswork.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Updated Question with code

Comment: @NigelRen Updated Question with code

Comment: Have you come across NOT `!` ?

Comment: Functions really should be coded outside a set of IF's